# Multiple Facebook 'send' buttons each with different descriptions on one page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, send, facebook-opengraph

I know that the 'send' button gets the content data from the og meta tags so my initial thought is that it's not possible and you can only share the entire page itself. Ideally I want to be able to send different sections of the page individually, each with their own descriptions.

So wondering if there is a way to have multiple 'send' buttons on a single page but with custom descriptions for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simulate this by having the buttons point to different URLs, each with separate meta tags, then redirect users that land on any of those URLs back to the 'main' URL - you can identify when it's Facebook crawling for the meta tags because the user agent will be the same each time, and redirect anyone else.

Comment: This is what I essentially ended up doing. I pointed them to the same url but with GET vars that denote which section of the page the send is referring to. The og meta tags are then displayed based on the GET flags.